# Eclipse plugin log is not printed immediately in console in swt button onclick event

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

For print the log in console I used

```
MessageConsole console = new MessageConsole("System Output", null); 
ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager().addConsoles(new IConsole[] { console });             ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager().showConsoleView(console);
MessageConsoleStream stream = console.newMessageStream();
System.setOut(new PrintStream(stream));
System.setErr(new PrintStream(stream));

String rootPath="D:/luna/sampleproject";
System.setProperty("file.log",rootPath+"logs/log_console.log");
```

it print the log properly 
My problem is it doesn't print the log in swt onclick event immediately. It print the log all process is completed.

my sample code is:

```
button_Ok.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            log.info("Before invoking the api call");
            CreateDesign create=new CreateDesign();
            boolean status=create.createDesign();//api invoked
            log.info("Api invokoing is completed...");
        }
```

}

Here the log messages are printed after complete the whole process of api invocation.

How do I print the log immediately of execution?

Comment: Its working well.I want to immediately print the log messages in the onclick event

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
new PrintStream(stream, true)
```

for the `PrintStream` constructors to get the stream flushed quicker.

Comment: Thanks for Your reply.I can try

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:
  I called the api call by using another thread like as 
button_Ok.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        log.info("Before invoking the api call");
        Thread thread = new Thread(new createDesigns());
        thread.start();
     }
```

}

In another class

public class createDesigns implements Runnable{

```
@Override
public void run() {
          CreateDesign create=new CreateDesign();
          boolean status=create.createDesign();//api invoked
}
```

}

So it prints the log immediately